# Problems with the Outlook API - Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a plugin for Outlook with a TreeView.

I know when the user drags the email but I don't know how to identify when the user drags a folder

After identify the object dragged , if it's a folder , will be made ​​the steps of the code below to get CurrentFolder , passing and publish for all the emails of the folder

```
Outlook.Application outlookApplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Outlook.Explorer outlookExplorer = (Outlook.Explorer)outlookApplication.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.Selection selection = outlookExplorer.Selection;
Outlook.Folder folder = (Outlook.Folder)outlookExplorer.CurrentFolder;
Outlook.Items items = folder.Items;
Outlook.MailItem mail = null;

for (int i = 1; i <= items.Count; i++) 
{
    if (items[i] is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        mail = (Outlook.MailItem)items[i]; 
        // Here I have all the mails and the plugin works to publish one or more mails like a Outlook.MailItems
    }
}
```

Someone know how can I to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone, I found a very ugly way to solve the problem , but it's what I need .

In the event args exists a lot of properties that one of these properties appears only when I dragged a folder. Look the code.

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("UniformResourceLocator"))
{
    // This step it's true only with a folder 
}
else
{
    // This step it's to others items like MailItem, ContactItem...
}
```

Someday it's will be util for someone.

Regards !!!